# Exchange 2010 transport rules with external mail

Tags: exchange

Firstly, I'm new with exchange 2010 and I'm learning about administrating in my job.

We have exchange 2010 in a business and we need to redirect a mail to external mail.

I search for information and I see that this is posible with transport rules, but I try to do a rule, and this fails at send the mail to external mail.

I try to explain with exemple:

Internal mail (internal@internal.com) [internal exchange 2010]
External mail (external@external.com)
Sender mail (sender@sender.com)

When sender@sender.com sends mail to internal@internal.com resend this mail to external@external.com.

To do this I did a rule.

Apply rule to messages
  of 'sender@sender.com'
and sent to 'internal@internal.com'
and redirect message to 'external@external.com'.

But this doesn't work for external mail.

I think that transport rule is active, because when i sent it, i can see in Management Console > Toolbox > Delivery report, that the mail is redirected to external@external.com but this is failing.

It says: 
"Not found this recipient. Check the email address. But the mail is correct."

It seems like only doesn't work external mail, because if I change the rule to internal@internal.local it works

What im doing wrong?

Thanks for all.

Comment: I would comment, but I dont have 50 points to do so; Does external@external.com exist in your exchange org? If not, create a contact for it and forward to the internal email address to the contact.

Comment: I did the contact and now exchange are trying to send mail and says me:

02/01/2014 19:16 server.internal.local
The email address of "internal@internal.local" recipient was updated to the e-mail "IMCEAIMAP internal-internal +40 +2 Ecom@internal.local". The message is in the process of being sent.

error
02/01/2014 19:16 server.internal.local
There was a problem delivering this message. Verify that the email address is correct.

Comment: There are too many variables that could cause this delivery to fail. I typically use contacts to forward mail outside my domain (using the Set as External flag in the Email Addresses tab) @rnxrx My post was an attempt at an answer, so yes, it does provide an answer to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the contact with an SMTP address of `mail@externaldomain.com` and uncheck the `automatically update email addresses" button.

In the EMC, in the actual mailbox (the original internal one) setup forwarding and choose to forward all email to this newly created contact.

That should handle it just fine if you are talking a broad sweep of all emails for that address.

Answer (score 0):

You can either wait a couple of hours until the new rule takes effect, or force it restarting the Transport Service.

> Each Hub Transport server maintains a recipient cache that's used to
>   look up recipient and distribution list information. The recipient
>   cache reduces the number of requests that each Hub Transport server
>   must make to an Active Directory domain controller. The recipient
>   cache updates every four hours. You can't modify the recipient cache
>   update interval. Therefore, changes to transport rule recipients, such
>   as the addition or removal of distribution list members, may not be
>   applied to transport rules until the recipient cache is updated. To
>   force an immediate update of the recipient cache, you must stop and
>   start the Microsoft Exchange Transport service. You must do this for
>   each Hub Transport server where you want to forcibly update the
>   recipient cache.

[Understanding How Transport Rules Are Applied.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124703.aspx)

Comment: I think that transport rule is active, because when i sent it, i can see in Management Console > Toolbox > Delivery report, that the mail is redirected to external@external.com but this is failing. says: Not found this recipient. Check the email address. But the mail is correct. It seems like only doesn't work external mail, because if I change the rule to internal@internal.com it works.